# Toggle facebook and twitter feed with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm trying to toggle between displaying facebook and twitter content with the following code:

```
function album(){

  var toggle=true;
FB.api(
          '/790876601057998','GET',{"fields":"albums{photos{picture,likes.summary(1).limit(0),comments.summary(1){from,message},name,created_time}}"},
          function(response) {
              var posts=response.albums.data.length;      
              var calls=posts;
               i=0;
              var l=response.albums.data[i].photos.data.length*5000;
              var image;
              var ima=[];
               j=0;
             count=0;

             var myVar;
             window.clearTimeout(myVar);
             function loop(){
             ( function next(i) {console.log(i);
                  len=response.albums.data[i].photos.data.length;
                  console.log("photos count:"+len);                
                   interval1=window.setInterval(function(){

                      $('#cf').hide();
                      $('#libtn').hide();
                      console.log("j:"+j)
                      image= document.createElement('img');
                      image.src= response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].picture;
                      document.getElementById('imgs').innerHTML='<img src="'+image.src+'">';
                      $('#imgs').hide();
                      likes=response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].likes.summary.total_count;
                      document.getElementById('likes').style.textAlign="center";
                      document.getElementById('likes').innerHTML=likes+"Likes";
                      $('#likes').hide();
                      response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].comments.total_count;
                      length=response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].comments.summary.total_count;
                      document.getElementById('name').innerHTML="";
                      document.getElementById('comment').innerHTML="";
                      document.getElementById('circle2').innerHTML="";
                      for(var k=0;k<length;k++){

                          var pro='/'+response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].comments.data[k].from.id+'/picture';
                          FB.api(pro,'GET',{"type":"small"},
                                  function(response) {

                                      im=document.createElement('img');
                                      im.src=response.data.url;
                                      document.getElementById('circle2').innerHTML='<img src="'+im.src+'">'+"<br />";


                          }
                          );

                         cmt=response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].comments.data[k].message;
                         name=response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].comments.data[k].from.name;
                         document.getElementById('name').innerHTML=name+":";
                         $('#name').hide();
                         document.getElementById('comment').innerHTML=cmt;
                         $('#comment').hide();
                         }  

                      $('#cf').hide().fadeIn(1000);
                         $('#circle2').hide().fadeIn(1000);
                         $('#name').hide().fadeIn(1000);
                         $('#comment').hide().fadeIn(1000);
                         $('#imgs').hide().fadeIn(1000);
                         $('#likes').hide().fadeIn(1000);
                         $('#libtn').hide().fadeIn(1000);
                         j++;
                         count++;

                         var id=((toggle==true)?'facebook':'twitter');

                         (function toggleDiv(divId) {
                             $("#"+divId).toggle();
                            if(toggle){
                                toggle=false;

                            }else{
                                toggle=true;
                                     $('#myList').hide().fadeIn(1000);
                                     $('#tweet_img').hide().fadeIn(1000);

                            }
                             })(id);
                        console.log("count"+count+"len"+len);
                      if(count==len){
                         console.log("set interval");
                         j=0;
                         count=0;
                        window.clearInterval(interval1);
                      }
                    /*  $(function(){
                          $(this).closest('div').next().slideToggle();
                        });*/

                     // interval1=window.setTimeout(loop1,5000);
              },5000);      

                  calls--;
                  /*if(calls==0){
                      console.log("set interval1");
                       window.clearInterval(interval); 
                       }*/
                  j=0;
                  count=0;
                  //loop1();
                  l=(response.albums.data[i].photos.data.length)*5000;
                  //console.log("l:"+l);
                  //window.setTimeout(loop,l);
                  myVar=window.setTimeout(function(){if(i!=posts){i++;next(i);}},l);
                  //}

                })(i);

              }
              if(calls!=0){
              console.log("here");
              loop();
              }
            setTimeout(function(){ window.clearInterval(interval1);window.clearTimeout(myVar);status();},60000);

          });         
}
```

But I am not getting the expected outcome(i.e toggling between facebook and twitter feed).

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: there´s a lot of very bad coding in that example. you should try doing stuff without jquery first, and you should learn about variable scoping. for example, you never define interval1, so it will be global. that being said, "this is my code and it does not work as expected" is a bit too broad, do some debugging and you will most likely find out what the problem is. where´s the twitter feed? why is that function called "album"? what does it do exactly? use better function names to describe functions.

Comment: this code is a part of a bigger project and twitter feed is retrieved by a servlet it is just being displayed in this code and this function is called album because it gets albums from facebook and displays the pictures in it one by one.The problem am getting is that i want fb and twitter feed to alternate but it is not doing so (i.e)it is either displaying 2 fb posts continuosly or 2 twitter feeds @luschn